# Swift Material Component Filled Text fields background color not work

Tags: swift, material-ui, material-components, material-components-ios

i write these lines of codes to change background color of filled textfield, but it not work:

```
import MaterialComponents

...

@IBOutlet weak var textfield: MDCFilledTextField!

let scheme = MDCContainerScheme()
scheme.colorScheme.backgroundColor = .red
scheme.colorScheme.onBackgroundColor = .green

textfield.label.text = "Phone number"
textfield.placeholder = "555-555-55"

textfield.applyTheme(withScheme: scheme)
textfield.sizeToFit()
```

and finally it looks like this:

[image]

but when i change primaryColor `scheme.colorScheme.primaryColor = .red` it works. ( just primary color )

Comment: Did you try to use `setFilledBackgroundColor:forState:` method?

Answer (score 4):

You can change the colors like following:

```
    let tf = MDCFilledTextField()

    // Background color
    tf.setFilledBackgroundColor(.clear, for: .normal)
    tf.setFilledBackgroundColor(Colors.textFieldActiveBackground, for: .editing)

    // Floating label color
    tf.setFloatingLabelColor(Colors.pinDotActive, for: .editing)
    tf.setFloatingLabelColor(Colors.grayScale800, for: .normal)
    
    // Underline color
    tf.setUnderlineColor(Colors.pinDotActive, for: .editing)
    tf.setUnderlineColor(Colors.grayScale800, for: .normal)
```